# Do internal traderoutes drain your host city?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

If I make an internal trade route within my empire, providing food or production to a distant city, does the provided food / production come from the host city? Or does the act of spending one of your limited trade routes in this way cause the material to poof out of thin air?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extra goods are generated via trade. Or “poofs out of thin air”. To me it makes sense: you are using your government’s military might to allow civilian trading transactions on designated routes.

Comment: Explanation makes sense, but are there any reliable sources (such as developer interview, or in-game help)?

Comment: @theUg Well, I've since confirmed this myself, so does that count?

Comment: Welcome to the site, National! We're a QA site, not a forum, so I've edited out the last line of your answer. Please see our [FAQ] if you have further questions!